# Подключение библиотеки android

Tags: android, библиотеки

Скопировал android-support-v7-appcompat.jar в папку libs проекта. В файле build.gradle добавил compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'. Но gradle говорит:

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1"
```

Почему L-версия? Как исправить?

Код активити:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если вы используете gradle, то нет необходимости добавлять jar в libs. Gradle сам подгрузит нужные библиотеки при сборке (загруженное можно увидеть в дереве проекта в разделе External libraries. Поэтому удалите jar из libs.
2. Вы добавляете супер новую версию версию библиотек обратной совместимости. Гугл выпустила их специально для разработчиков, чтобы они могли использовать её плюшки для подготовки своих приложений к релизу ОС Android L. Так как эта самая Android L не вышла, то гугл ограничила разработчиков на использования этих плюшек, путем ограничения minSdkVersion = L. Поэтому используйте пока более младшие версии библиотек обратной совместимости.

   ```
   dependencies {   
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо. Но теперь при сборке gradle выдает:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hangover.a52_timepickerdialog/com.hangover.a52_timepickerdialog.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
Т.е. ему почему то не нравится тема. На AppCompat я изменил, но ошибка та же. Что не так?

Comment: Я изменил в манифесте на AppCompat и ошибка исчезла. Но до сих пор не понял, почему ему иногда не нравится тема?

Comment: @compl Это уже следующий вопрос. Возможно у вас есть несколько стилей для разных версий ОС. Если так, то измените во всех местах. Без кода Activity и содержимого стиля трудно сказать.

Comment: Добавил код активити

Comment: @compl Создайте новый вопрос с новой проблемой и изложите всю суть туда. И в вопросе не код Activity, а описание вида для активити.